# Method to find raspi's usb current output

Tags: usb, pi-2, usb-power, usb-hub

I am working on a project and I need to connect 4 mobile phones to raspberry pi (Pi-2). I need to charge phones as well. I know that raspi itself cannot charge 4 phones so I bought some usb hub with external power source but I want to be sure it is working. So I was wondering there is a method that I can find raspi's usb current output. Thanks!

TL;DR is there a method to measure raspi's usb current output (from software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no software to monitor USB current.

You will need to add external hardware and write your own software.